# Need help interpreting this symbol

Tags: number-theory, notation

I came across this symbol while reading about number theory what does it mean?

> [image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $\exists$ means "exists", e.g. $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x^2=1$ means "there exists an x in the real numbers that squares to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\exists$ is a [logic symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) that means "there exists".  Also popular is $\forall$, which means "for all".